# How to enable Select Box when edit button from jquery-tabledit is clicked?

Tags: php, html, tabledit

I have a table with a select box that I want to be disabled by default (for safety purposes). Now, when the edit button from jquery-tabledit is clicked, I want it to be enabled again. How could I achieve so? When clicking on Save, action_user_2.php gets called with [action] => edit, but I need to listen when edit button gets click on the same page so that I can change the select box to "select name='selectbox'" (removing disabled).

```
<!--User Approval-->
    <td>
        <form method='POST'>
            if ($row_approved['admin_approved'] == 'Approved') {
            echo "<select disabled name='selectbox' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                <option value='Approved' selected>Approved</option>
                <option value='Disapproved'>Disapproved</option>
            </select>";
            } else if ($row_approved['admin_approved'] == 'Disapproved') {
            echo "<select name='selectbox' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                <option value='Approved'>Approved</option>
                <option value='Disapproved' selected>Disapproved</option>
            </select>";
            }
            echo "
        </form>
    </td>

    <!--User Roles-->
    <td>
    <form method='POST'>
    <select disabled class='roles_checkbox' multiple='multiple' name="roles_checkbox[]"
            onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    </select>
<?php
echo "
    </form>
    </td>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#editable_table').Tabledit({

            // when click on save; action_user_2.php gets called
            url: 'action_user_2.php', // where data will be sent
            
            data: {approved_status: approved_status},
            columns: {
                identifier: [0, "user_id"],
                editable: [[1, 'first_name'],
                    [2, 'last_name'],
                    [3, 'email']]
            },
            // hide the column that has the identifier
            hideIdentifier: true,

            // activate focus on first input of a row when click in save button
            autoFocus: true,

            // activate save button when click on edit button
            saveButton: true,

            restoreButton: false,
            onSuccess: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var htmlString = "<?php echo 'User information has been updated'; ?>";
                alert(htmlString);

                // custom action buttons
                if (data.action === 'delete') {
                    $('#' + data.id).remove();
                }
            }
        });

    });
    $('#editable_table').DataTable();
</script>
```

action_user_2.php

```
$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
print_r($input);
```

console->network->action_user_2.php

```
Array ( [user_id] => 4 [first_name] => New [last_name] => User [email] => tes@gmail.com [action] => edit )
```

Comment: What would help you get answers more than offering a bounty would be creating a minimal example - a table with some hardcoded data, all set up to be used with the two plugins you're combining. There's way too much that needs to be recreated in order to test the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).closest("tr").find("[name=selectbox]")` here `closest()` will get `tr` where button is been clicked and then `find()` method will find your select-box inside that tr then simply remove disabled from that select-box

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#editable_table').Tabledit({
  //some codes...
  columns: {
    identifier: [0, "user_id"],
    editable: [
      [1, 'first_name'],
      [2, 'last_name'],
      [3, 'email'],

    ]
  },
  // hide the column that has the identifier
  hideIdentifier: true,

  // activate focus on first input of a row when click in save button
  autoFocus: true,

  // activate save button when click on edit button
  saveButton: true,

  restoreButton: false,
  onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var htmlString = "<?php echo 'User information has been updated'; ?>";
    alert(htmlString);

    // custom action buttons
    if (data.action === 'delete') {
      $('#' + data.id).remove();
    }
  }


});

$(document).on("click", ".tabledit-edit-button", function() {
  //get closest tr and then find slectbox and disable same
  $(this).closest("tr").find("[name=selectbox]").removeAttr('disabled')

  $(this).closest("tr").find("[name*=roles_checkbox]").removeAttr('disabled')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-tabledit@1.0.0/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="editable_table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>user_id</th>
      <th>first_name</th>
      <th>last_name</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>Approved</th>
      <th>Soemthing</th>
      <th class="tabledit-toolbar-column"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthing..
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthing..1
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthinga@gmail.com
      </td>
      <td>
        <form method='POST'>
          <select disabled name='selectbox' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value='Approved' selected>Approved</option>
            <option value='Disapproved'>Disapproved</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </td>

      <!--User Roles-->
      <td>
        <form method='POST'>
          <select disabled class='roles_checkbox' multiple='multiple' name="roles_checkbox[]" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value='1' selected>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
          </select>

        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthing..
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthing..2
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthinga@gmail.com
      </td>
      <td>
        <form method='POST'>
          <select disabled name='selectbox' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value='Approved' selected>Approved</option>
            <option value='Disapproved'>Disapproved</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </td>

      <!--User Roles-->
      <td>
        <form method='POST'>
          <select disabled class='roles_checkbox' multiple='multiple' name="roles_checkbox[]" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value='1' selected>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
          </select>

        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How would you implemented your answer for the <!--User Roles-->? 
I tried: ```$(this).closest("tr").find("[name=roles_checkbox[]]").removeAttr('disabled')``` and it doesn't work

Comment: Hi, like this : `$(this).closest("tr").find("[name*=roles_checkbox]").removeAttr('disabled')` Updated in answer as well .

Comment: I created a new question for a new related issue. Please see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013359/how-to-enable-dropdown-select-box-when-edit-button-from-jquery-tabledit-is-click) if interested.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly you want to click the edit button to edit the current row fields, and the select with `name="roles_checkbox[]"` to become `name="selectbox"` and also remove `disabled` attribute?

if yes then you can try the "onclick" event I've added

```
......
.......

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("click", ".tableit-edit-button", function() {
        $(".roles_checkbox").attr("name", "selectbox").removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    $('#editable_table').Tabledit({
    .........
    .........
```