# How to enable DropDown Select Box when edit button from jquery-tabledit is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, html, tabledit

I have a table with a dropdown select box that I want to be disabled by default (for safety purposes). Now, when the edit button from jquery-tabledit is clicked, I want it to be enabled again. How could I achieve so?
Whenever "Multiselect JS" is commented it works, but not otherwise. I need "Multiselect JS" so that it shows as a dropdown select box.

This is how it looks when "Multiselect JS" is commented:

[image]

You can find demo code in the accepted answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800551/how-to-enable-select-box-when-edit-button-from-jquery-tabledit-is-clicked/65995291?noredirect=1#comment116713521_65995291)

This question is different because it includes:

```
<!--Multiselect JS-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.roles_checkbox').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            nonSelectedText: '--Select Role--'
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<!--User Approval-->
    <td>
        <form method='POST'>
            if ($row_approved['admin_approved'] == 'Approved') {
            echo "<select disabled name='selectbox' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                <option value='Approved' selected>Approved</option>
                <option value='Disapproved'>Disapproved</option>
            </select>";
            } else if ($row_approved['admin_approved'] == 'Disapproved') {
            echo "<select name='selectbox' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                <option value='Approved'>Approved</option>
                <option value='Disapproved' selected>Disapproved</option>
            </select>";
            }
            echo "
        </form>
    </td>

    <!--User Roles-->
    <td>
    <form method='POST'>
    <select disabled class='roles_checkbox' multiple='multiple' name="roles_checkbox[]"
            onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    </select>
    <?php
    echo "
    </form>
    </td>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#editable_table').Tabledit({

            // when click on save; action_user_2.php gets called
            url: 'action_user_2.php', // where data will be sent
            
            data: {approved_status: approved_status},
            columns: {
                identifier: [0, "user_id"],
                editable: [[1, 'first_name'],
                    [2, 'last_name'],
                    [3, 'email']]
            },
            // hide the column that has the identifier
            hideIdentifier: true,

            // activate focus on first input of a row when click in save button
            autoFocus: true,

            // activate save button when click on edit button
            saveButton: true,

            restoreButton: false,
            onSuccess: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var htmlString = "<?php echo 'User information has been updated'; ?>";
                alert(htmlString);

                // custom action buttons
                if (data.action === 'delete') {
                    $('#' + data.id).remove();
                }
            }
        });

    $(document).on("click", ".tabledit-edit-button", function() {
    //get closest tr and then find slectbox and disable same
    $(this).closest("tr").find("[name=selectbox]").removeAttr('disabled')
    $(this).closest("tr").find("[name*=roles_checkbox]").removeAttr('disabled')
    })
  });

  $('#editable_table').DataTable();
</script>

<!--Multiselect JS-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.roles_checkbox').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            nonSelectedText: '--Select Role--'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable Select Box when edit button from jquery-tabledit is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800551/how-to-enable-select-box-when-edit-button-from-jquery-tabledit-is-clicked)

Comment: @Dr.Andrew no, it does not. I posted both questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are removing **disable** from select-box only but , elements which are dynamically generated from  mutliselect plugin are still disabled so you need to remove **disable** from that elements as well.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#editable_table').Tabledit({
  //some codes...
  columns: {
    identifier: [0, "user_id"],
    editable: [
      [1, 'first_name'],
      [2, 'last_name'],
      [3, 'email'],

    ]
  },
  hideIdentifier: true,
  autoFocus: true,
  saveButton: true,

  restoreButton: false,
  onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var htmlString = "<?php echo 'User information has been updated'; ?>";
    alert(htmlString);

    // custom action buttons
    if (data.action === 'delete') {
      $('#' + data.id).remove();
    }
  }


});

$(document).on("click", ".tabledit-edit-button", function() {
  //get closest tr and then find slectbox and disable same
  $(this).closest("tr").find("[name=selectbox]").removeAttr('disabled')

  $(this).closest("tr").find("[name*=roles_checkbox] , .dropdown-toggle ").removeAttr('disabled') //remove attr from button as well
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass('disabled') //remove disable class from button
})
$('.roles_checkbox').multiselect({
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  nonSelectedText: '--Select Role--',
  buttonWidth: '150px'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.16/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" integrity="sha512-DJ1SGx61zfspL2OycyUiXuLtxNqA3GxsXNinUX3AnvnwxbZ+YQxBARtX8G/zHvWRG9aFZz+C7HxcWMB0+heo3w==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.16/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js" integrity="sha512-ljeReA8Eplz6P7m1hwWa+XdPmhawNmo9I0/qyZANCCFvZ845anQE+35TuZl9+velym0TKanM2DXVLxSJLLpQWw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-tabledit@1.0.0/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="editable_table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>user_id</th>
      <th>first_name</th>
      <th>last_name</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>Approved</th>
      <th>Soemthing</th>
      <th class="tabledit-toolbar-column"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthing..
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthing..1
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthinga@gmail.com
      </td>
      <td>
        <form method='POST'>
          <select disabled name='selectbox' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value='Approved' selected>Approved</option>
            <option value='Disapproved'>Disapproved</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </td>

      <!--User Roles-->
      <td>
        <form method='POST'>
          <select disabled class='roles_checkbox' multiple='multiple' name="roles_checkbox[]" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>

            <option value="3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
          </select>

        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthing..
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthing..2
      </td>
      <td>
        Soemthinga@gmail.com
      </td>
      <td>
        <form method='POST'>
          <select disabled name='selectbox' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value='Approved' selected>Approved</option>
            <option value='Disapproved'>Disapproved</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </td>

      <!--User Roles-->
      <td>
        <form method='POST'>
          <select disabled class='roles_checkbox' multiple='multiple' name="roles_checkbox[]" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
            <!-- Option 3 will be selected in advance ... -->
            <option value="3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
          </select>

        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works great on my table when commenting ```//buttonWidth: '150px'```